# High memory usage using mqtt

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm running a script in a terminal that sends mqtt messages. These messages are big arrays (I want to simulate the sending of images). So the code for the sender is as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

mqttBroker = "localhost"
mqttClient = "Sender"

client = mqtt.Client(mqttClient)
client.connect(mqttBroker)

while True:
    arr = np.random.random((424,240,4)).astype(np.float32)
    arr = arr.tobytes()
    topic = "myDataName"
    client.publish(topic,payload=arr)
```

The code for the receiver is:

```
import numpy as np
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global n
    data = np.frombuffer(message.payload, dtype=np.float32).reshape(424,240,4)
    n += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    global n
    n=0
    mqttBroker = "localhost"
    mqttClient = "Receiver"

    client = mqtt.Client(mqttClient)
    client.connect(mqttBroker)

    client.subscribe("myDataName")

    client.on_message = on_message

    client.loop_start()

    while True:
        continue
```

I'm running this two script in two different terminals. I installed mosquitto-1.6.0 (it's the broker) and I'm on Windows 10 x64.

The problem is that mosquitto.exe will fill all the memory of my computer (32Gb RAM) until the messages are delivered. If I terminate the sender, the receiver continues to receive the messages and mosquitto.exe begins to free up the memory. As I want to send images, I am not interested in previous messages (images). I just want the latest image sent at any point. So, previous messages can be discarded if there are new ones.

Can someone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: MQTT is not a good way to stream raw high frame rate video (which is effectively what you are doing here) add a sensible (e.g. 0.1 seconds) delay to your publisher. Any camera you use to actually feed this would likely be ~24fps

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @hardillb. Do you have any suggestions I can use for streaming images with python?

Comment: I'm more suggesting that a super tight loop publishing is not a realistic test, which is why I suggested adding a realistic delay

Comment: Thank you, @hardillb. I will take a further look.